# { $v$, $Av$, .... , $A^{n-1}v$} forms a basis of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ be an n*n matrix such that $A^n =0$ but
$A^{n-1}$ not equal 0.

> Prove, there exist $ v\in \mathbb R^n $such that
>   { $v$, $Av$, .... , $A^{n-1}v$} forms a basis of $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Since $A^{n-1}$ is different from $0$, choose a vector $v$ such that $A^{n-1}v\not=0$. Next show that  $\{v,Av,A^2v,...,A^{n-1}v\}$ is a base. It suffices to show that this set is linearly independent. It follows that it is a base because it has size $n$.

A hint for showing linear independence:

Let $c_0,c_2,...,c_{n-1}$ be any real numbers such that:
$$c_0v+c_1Av+c_2A^2v+...+c_{n-1}A^{n-1}v=0$$

Apply $A^{n-1}$ to the above equation, what do you get ?

Proceed inductively to deduce that $c_1=c_2=...=c_{n-1}=0$

Comment: @robjohn $v$ can't be zero, otherwise $A^{n-1}v$ would be zero

Comment: @robjohn I mentioned at the begining that $v$ is chosen so that $A^{n-1}v$ is chosen so that it is non-zero

Comment: @robjohn Yes which is what is desired, I wish to show that $c_0=...c_{n-1}=0$

Comment: @robjohn I am only trying to deduce that $c_0=...=c_{n-1}$, I am not trying to deduce that $v=0$, hope this makes it clearer

Comment: Yes. Your answer is good. Sorry for the interruption (+1)

Comment: @robjohn No problem at all :)